# Irony: Tutorial on evaluating AST nodes?

Tags: c#, irony

I've defined a simple grammar in [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/), and generated a nice compact AST.

[image]

Now I'm trying to figure out how to evaluate it. Problem is, I can't find any tutorials on how to do this.

I've defined just 2 AST nodes:

```
class TagListNode : AstNode
{
    public override void Init(ParsingContext context, ParseTreeNode treeNode)
    {
        base.Init(context, treeNode);
        AsString = "TagList";
        foreach (var node in treeNode.ChildNodes)
            AddChild(null, node);
    }

    public override void EvaluateNode(Irony.Interpreter.EvaluationContext context, AstMode mode)
    {
        foreach (var node in ChildNodes)
            node.EvaluateNode(context, AstMode.Read);
    }
}

class TagBlockNode : AstNode
{
    public AstNode Content;

    public override void Init(ParsingContext context,ParseTreeNode treeNode)
    {
        base.Init(context, treeNode);
        AsString = treeNode.ChildNodes[0].FindTokenAndGetText();
        Content = AddChild(null, treeNode.ChildNodes[1]);
    }

    public override void EvaluateNode(EvaluationContext context, AstMode mode)
    {
        context.Write(string.Format("<{0}>", AsString));
        Content.EvaluateNode(context, AstMode.Read);
        context.Write(string.Format("</{0}>", AsString));
    }
}
```

This will generate the following output:

```
 <html><head><title></title></head><body><h1></h1><p></p><p></p></body></html>3.14159265358979
```

Whereas the output I want is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>page title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>header</h1>
        <p>paragraph 1</p>
        <p>3.14159265358979</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't think I'm supposed to be using `Context.Write()`. The samples show pushing stuff onto `context.Data` and popping them off... but I'm not quite sure how that works.

I'm guessing `pi` gets tacked on at the end because it's automatically pushed onto `context.Data` and then one element is popped off at the end?? I'm not really sure.

Some pointers or a link to a tutorial would be nice.

Also, how am I supposed to handle the different node types? Each "Tag" can have 4 different types of content: another tag, a string literal, a variable, or a number. Should I be writing things like `if(node is StringLiteral) ....` in the `EvaluateNode` method or what?

---

I've found [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/YourFirstDSL.aspx) but they just loop over the AST and don't take advantage of `EvaluateNode`.

And then [this one](http://intellect.dk/post/Writing-a-calculator-in-C-using-Irony.aspx) which *replaces* a single value in the data stack...but doesn't really explain how this gets outputted or anything.

---

**To be clear, I specifically want to know how to override the `EvaluateNode` methods in `Irony.Ast.AstNode` to do what I want.**

---

Okay, I've traced that tidbit at the end to this line:

```
    if (EvaluationContext.HasLastResult)
      EvaluationContext.Write(EvaluationContext.LastResult + Environment.NewLine);
```

Which is included in the default evaluation routine....perhaps it works well for a calculator app, but not so much in mine. Trying to figure out how to bypass the script interpreter now, but then I don't know how to set the globals.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to iterate through an AST structure is to implement the visitor [pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternVisitor.aspx).

Maybe this [link](http://www.nootaikok.com/2009/01/c-code-generation-using-mgrammar.html) helps you.

Comment: Sorry, neither of those links are very helpful... pretty sure Irony already employs the visitor pattern, and mgrammar != irony.

Comment: @Mark, if you dont want to use if-else at the TagBlockNode.EvaluateNode, i think that your grammar should create a new AstNode from the value of the tag and override the method or maybe iterate trough the TagBlockNode child calling ToString() ?¿?.